# Search csv file column

Tags: scripts, csv

Is there a way to search the content of a specific column of a csv file using the terminal. But that it still returns all the information of the rest of the columns.

I want to be able to search for a string in a column of a csv file and if it matches return all of the information in the same Row

Is there away of implementing it into a shell bash file and ask the user what string to search

Comment: You can use `awk`. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: How would I use the awk command @muru

Comment: Like so: `awk -F, '$N == 'some string'`, replacing N with the column number under consideration.

Comment: Where would I enter the file name

Comment: Where would I add the file name @muru

Comment: At the end of the command.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F',' '$N == "string to search"' filename.csv
```

Replace N with column number and filename.csv with filename to search

Comment: How could you implement this into a shell bash file and ask the user the string to search @KasiyA

Comment: `printf "please enter pattern to search:\n%s"; read pattern; awk -v patt="$pattern" -F',' '$N == patt' filename.csv`

Comment: Could you be more clear in your answer @KasiyA

Comment: `printf "please enter pattern to search:\n%s"` jut prints the `please enter pattern to search:` then prints a new-line(`\n`). `read pattern` read from stdin and store the input into `pattern` variable. then in `-v patt="$pattern"`, stored or entered string from user, copies into awk `patt` local variable and rest of the command search in column $N if it's equal with user entered input.

Comment: I have tried what you said and it does not display any results

Comment: Because you have to change `$N` to your specific column that you want to search from there and file name and What is the problem NOW ;)

Comment: I did change the n and file name and it does not Echo any results of the search it just ends @KasiyA

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19516/discussion-between-kasiya-and-jhondoe).

Comment: How would you search non case sensitive

Comment: How about in case sensitive @KasiyA

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your string to search is "name" in the 4th column, then use

```
awk -F ',' '$4 ~ /^name$/' filename.csv
```